# Create a customized tensorflow layer to separate features

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

To solve the issue that I've posted here : [Adjust the output of a CNN as an input for TimeDistributed tensorflow layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68245361/adjust-the-output-of-a-cnn-as-an-input-for-timedistributed-tensorflow-layer) which is about *input data format of the Time distributed tensorflow layer*, I think about another idea: instead of passing two inputs to a CNN model, what if , before designing the CNN model, I merge the two inputs in one input using pandas or numpy, and then pass it to the *CNN* model and then *AFTER* the *INPUT LAYER* and *BEFORE* the *CONVOLUTION LAYER*, I **add a customized layer that separate feature that I concatenate them** !! Is this possible ? the following picture explain more what I am talking about:
[image]

Comment: you don't need to create a custom layer... you can separate the input simply using index slicing

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Marco  for the help. Exactly like Marco says, I separate the input using index slicing and was done using a **Lambda layer**. This is the code:

```py
input_layer1=tf.keras.Input(shape=(input_shape))
separate_features1 = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x : tf.transpose(x,[0,1,2,3])[:,:-1,:,:])(input_layer1)
separate_features2 = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x : tf.transpose(x,[0,1,2,3])[:,-1:,:,:])(input_layer1)
```

This is the model architecture:

[image]